# Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n \leq b\ \forall n$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$, same $a$, then $a \leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n \leq b\ \forall n$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$, same $a$, then $a \leq b$.

Trying to prove this rigorously. we know $(a_n)$ is bounded if $\exists\ M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n| \leq M\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have $a_n \rightarrow a$, so $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, n \geq N, |a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

So at a glance, it's clear to me why this is true, since every element of the sequence is bounded by $b$, whatever the sequence converges also is. But stuck on showing this rigorously.

Comment: Note that "every element of the sequence is... therefore the limit is... also" is a **very** dodgy argument.  For example, "every element of the sequence $\{\frac{n}{n+1}\}$ is less than $1$, therefore the limit is less than $1$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of proof, you can fill in the details.

Suppose $a>b$.  Choose $\epsilon=a-b$, which is positive.

By definition of limit, for large enough $n$ we have
$$|a_n-a|<\epsilon$$
so
$$a_n-a>-\epsilon$$
so
$$a_n>b$$
which is a contradiction.